# Datastore - flow no emits new value after change

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, datastore, kotlin-flow

I cannot receive changes in the data store. After changing the database mode in the settings on the main screen the app should observe another source of data.

```
@Singleton
class SettingsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) : SettingsRepository {
    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "user_prefs")

 override val databaseMode: Flow<String>
        get() =
            context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
                preferences[DATABASE_MODE_KEY] ?: DatabaseMode.LOCAL.name
            }.distinctUntilChanged()

/// Viewmodel ->
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            observeDatabaseModeUseCase().collect { databaseMode ->
                observeAllProductsUseCase(databaseMode).map { products ->
                    getFilteredProductListUseCase(
                        products,
                        filterProductDataState.value.filterProduct
                    )
                }.collect {
                    _uiState.value = MyPantryProductsUiState.Loaded(
                        MyPantryModel(
                            groupsProduct = getGroupProductListUseCase(it),
                            loadingVisible = false
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried all dispatchers. I don't know why It's not emitting new values after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're collecting an infinite flow inside another flow's collection block. So when the first item from the outer flow is emitted, it starts collecting the inner flow forever and a second item of the outer flow can never be emitted. Use `flatMapLatest` instead. This will make it interrupt the secondary flow whenever the first flow emits a new item.

```
//In ViewModel init:
observeDatabaseModeUseCase()
    .flatMapLatest { databaseMode ->
        observeAllProductsUseCase(databaseMode)
    }.map { products ->
        getFilteredProductListUseCase(
            products,
            filterProductDataState.value.filterProduct
        )
    }.onEach {
        _uiState.value = MyPantryProductsUiState.Loaded(
            MyPantryModel(
                groupsProduct = getGroupProductListUseCase(it),
                loadingVisible = false
            )
        )
    }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default) // probably unnecessary since you don't seem to be doing blocking work.
    .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

You didn't show what `_uiState` is, but possibly you can make it a StateFlow using `stateIn` on the above to simplify your code.

Comment: _uiState is MutableStateFlow. Now it's working. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at the stateIn operator. It will clean up your code. You don't need to have a separate `MutableStateFlow` property and do this in an `init` block.